# Upgrading mongodb has no effect and still shows the old version

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Following are the commands which I used to upgrade my mongodb version from 2.6.9 to latest, but its still showing me the previous version. Let me know what I am doing wrong with the upgrading process. The problem is that `mongod -version` still shows the old version installed after upgrade.

Docs which I refer to - [Mongodb Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

Steps I followed -

- sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
- echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

Result -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mongodb-org
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 139 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,608 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/ trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse mongodb-org amd64 3.0.2 [3,608 B]
Fetched 3,608 B in 0s (18.3 kB/s)      
(Reading database ... 298790 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org_3.0.2_amd64.deb ...
arg: upgrade
Unpacking mongodb-org (3.0.2) over (2.6.9) ...
Setting up mongodb-org (3.0.2) ...
```

After this I re started the service - `sudo service mongod restart`

But still its showing me version `2.6.9` Let me know what I am doing wrong here..or missed any step ?

Comment: Make a backup of your db, than purge package `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org`, and install with provided steps.

Comment: @vanadium23 I believe its the last option ..can't we have something in between ?

Comment: Visit this: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/?_ga=1.257599176.252533426.1426494053

Comment: @GauravDave Have you read the question ? I already mentioned this link

Comment: I have given again, so that you can re-visit and see, if you have missed out any point.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I'm in the exact same situation, followed the exact same steps, and had the same issue.

What worked for me was:

[Uninstalling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#uninstall-mongodb):

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge "mongodb-org*"
```

**Do NOT remove data directories** - all your data will be lost if you do.

Don't forget the quotes to prevent shell from interpreting.

Note: Calling `sudo apt-get purge "mongodb-org*"` deletes the `mongod.conf` file. In case you want to keep this file after the update, make sure you **create a backup copy** of it and use it after the new version has been installed.

Then [install mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-the-mongodb-packages) with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

This assumes that you've already performed the previous installation steps (importing the public key, creating a list file, reloading local package database) as you've stated.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall/purge.  Instead explicitly tell the mongo installer to install the exact version you want, and it will work.  There is a final step added at the end of the official docs which the OP did not do.  This answer does, and it works:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34667652/404699

Comment: RE steampowered's comment, that "final step" was: `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.6.23 mongodb-org-server=3.6.23 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.23 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.23 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.23` and it was presented as an optional alternative to `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`. The instructions are wrong because the latter doesn't actually install the newest version. You *must* to use the big *versioned* install command for it to work. (This is true for [the official 3.4 to 3.6 upgrade tutorial/docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), at least)

Answer (score 31):

[*Disclaimer*] Before going into upgrade consider that moving from 2.6 to 3.+ requires an update on storage files. Same if you are updating from 3.2 to 3.4 or 3.4 to 3.6. **Important:** You can't *directly* upgrade from 3.2 to 3.6, for example. You must upgrade "step by step" 3.2-->3.4-->3.6. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318487/error-while-upgrading-mongodb-from-3-2-to-3-6) for details.

This is necessary if you want to recover your old DBs

As of writing 3.6 is the latest version of MongoDB. Some details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/)

Beware that changing between versions also regards some syntax in .conf file.

[*Procedure*] A more general framework for updating is to follow the typical procedure as shown [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), but point to "Install a specific release of MongoDB" part of this guide as you already have MongoDB installed.

An example on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.2.18 mongodb-org-server=3.2.18 mongodb-org-shell=3.2.18 mongodb-org-mongos=3.2.18 mongodb-org-tools=3.2.18
```

Comment: This worked, just that 3.2.0 should be replaced with whatever version you want to install

Comment: This solution works with whatever version of Mongo and Ubuntu. And I think is  way better than the other.  Problem is that you need to update data from 2.6 -> 3.+ and even when stepping like this 3.2 -> 3.4 -> 3.6

I would put a disclaimer on this answer with some link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/

Comment: @sparaflAsh Thanks. Fell free to edit the answer and gain some reputation ;)

Answer (score 12):

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```

Answer (score 9):

You should update each package manually. So try:

`dpkg -l | grep mongo`

```
ii  mongodb-org                              3.2.10                                      amd64        MongoDB open source document-oriented database system (metapackage)
ii  mongodb-org-mongos                       3.2.10                                      amd64        MongoDB sharded cluster query router
hi  mongodb-org-server                       3.2.10                                     amd64        MongoDB database server
ii  mongodb-org-shell                        3.2.14                                     amd64        MongoDB shell client
ii  mongodb-org-tools                        3.2.14                                     amd64        MongoDB tools
```

and then update each pakage manually

`sudo apt-get install mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools`

Answer (score 6):

You can replace binaries to upgrade to mongodb 3.0 as follows (works on Ubuntu/CentOs but commands are listed for Ubuntu) :

1. Download tar from mongodb website as per your destribution from : https://www.mongodb.org/downloads
2. Untar downloaded file.

   tar -zxvf {mongo-tar-file}.tgz
3. Stop mongod service.

   sudo service mongod stop
4. Replace binaries from your tar/bin to /usr/bin.

   cd {your-extracted-folder}/bin

   sudo mv -f * /usr/bin/
5. Start mongod service.

   sudo service mongod start

After you connect to mongo after this, you can see version has been updated. I have upgraded in this way on my production servers without any issue.

> You should backup your data before upgrading. Usually no
>   backup/restore is necessary but sometimes things don't
>   go as expected.

Answer (score 3):

***Step 1: First you need to uninstall existing mongodb***

1. **stop Mongodb service**

   sudo service mongod stop
2. **Remove Packages.**

   sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
3. **Remove Data Directories. (optional)**

   sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb

   sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb

---

***Step 2: Then Install latest mongodb (i.e. 3.4)***

**1. Import the public key used by the package management system.**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
```

**2. Create a list file for MongoDB. (Ubuntu 16.04)**

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

**3. Reload local package database.**

sudo apt-get update

**4. Install the latest stable version of MongoDB**

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

**5. Start MongoDB.**

sudo service mongod start

**6. Verify that MongoDB has started successfully**

> Verify that the mongod process has started successfully by checking
> the contents of the log file at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log for a line
> reading
>
> [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port
>
> where  is the port configured in /etc/mongod.conf, 27017 by default.

Comment: Had to delete the configs and now `db.version()` showing the updated version. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thank. I action step by step this is done on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Download tar from mongodb website as per your destribution from : https://www.mongodb.org/downloads
Untar downloaded file.

tar -zxvf {mongo-tar-file}.tgz

Stop mongod service.

sudo service mongod stop

Replace binaries from your tar/bin to /usr/bin.

cd {your-extracted-folder}/bin

sudo mv -f * /usr/bin/

Start mongod service.

sudo service mongod start

Answer (score 1):

In a situation we run into this issue because we still have in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` the `.list` file for mongodb-org's repository v4.2.

When we removed, and redone a `apt update` we are finally able to *reeally* update to 4.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting an error each time use command
`sudo apt-get update`.
They still try to get the old version and ask pgp key for each version. The things u need to do is go to path `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and delete file `mongodb-org-<version>.list` u need to delete after using
`sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*` command.
Use `sudo apt-get update`
again, it worked for me.