# Cant update mongodb on ubuntu 12

Tags: linux, mongodb

Whenever i try to update my my mongodb from mongod-org i get this error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EebRp.png)
I have tried `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*` and then installing it again But was no help.

Comment: Lakshay, i can advise this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999360/upgrading-mongo-version-from-2-6-9-to-latest-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts where an answer exists with 21 vote up.

Comment: The reason why StackOverflow doesn't allow you to post an image at your current rep level is so that you should be learning to paste the "text" and not a screenshot.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have tried this thread but i couldnt solve the issue.

Comment: @NeilLunn Okay, I'll try to use text only in next questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww Thanks for your suggestion. I've put my question there too.