# Error while upgrading Mongodb from 3.2 to 3.6

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, data-migration

I needed to upgrade mongodb from 3.2 to 3.6 in my environment. For the process i first migrated from 3.2 to 3.4 as recommended. After successful migration to 3.4, i started migration to 3.6 i am not able to start mongod. When checked log file i found error like:
 **IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.**

MY Mongod.conf

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I have similar problem, I've upgraded on **Ubuntu 16.04** from MongoDB 3.4 to 3.6 but I missed this important step

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

Then I must downgrade to 3.4 to do it and then upgrade to 3.6 again. Here is the detail steps:

**1. Uninstall 3.6**

Backup `/etc/mongod.conf`
Backup `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.listed` (rename or move it to another folder)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```

**2. Re-install 3.4**
Check folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to see if this file exists or not: `mongodb-org-3.4.list`. 
If it does not exist, you can re-create by this command:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
```

then install by `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
mongod --version
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

In my case the command `systemctl start mongod` return error `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found` I resolved by these commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
sudo service mongod restart
sudo service mongod status
```

**3. Execute very important command**
After downgrade to 3.4, run this

```
mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.10
> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
{ "featureCompatibilityVersion" : "3.4", "ok" : 1 }
> exit
```

**4. Upgrade 3.6 again**
Restore this file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.listed`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
```

Restore `/etc/mongod.conf`. Now, MongoDB 3.6 started without any problem

Comment: Just a small correction, apt-get is missing on these commands:
sudo remove mongodb-org-mongos
sudo remove mongodb-org-server
sudo remove mongodb-org-shell
sudo remove mongodb-org-tools

Comment: And a little recommendation: check `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` on all the replica set members with: `db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-replica-set/#prerequisites)

Comment: I had to add --allow-unauthenticated during step "2. Re-install 3.4"
`sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org --allow-unauthenticated`

Comment: I had to add the repo-key for mongodb-org:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6

Comment: very helpful - I missed the same step and this allowed me to recover

Comment: Mistype: filename should be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list`, not `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.listed`. Can you please correct you answer (replaceing `listed` to `list`)?

Comment: The missing step should be in blinking red on all upgrade from 3.2 to 3.6 documentation. Thanks for the instructions.

Answer (score 3):

This may be the case when your db folder contains old mongoDB database format (like 3.4)

here is a useful hack **if you don't mind LOOSING ALL YOUR DATA**

- After **saving it** you can delete the content of `/data/db` folder (ubuntu/linux mint)
- Then restart `mongod`, then it should work normally

Comment: This works well, given that the data hosted in the folder is not needed and so can be deleted.

Comment: But this cannot solve the problem which the old data is stored, and I want the old data back

Comment: The /data/db folder cannot be removed because you will lose all your data. This is a workaround not a solution

Comment: Oh no, this will delete all your existing data. Please be mindful of such cases