# Using brew upgrade Mongo update from 3.4 to 4.0 error: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0

Tags: mongodb

```
mongod
```

I got the following error

** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 before attempting an upgrade to 4.0; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/4.0-upgrade-fcv for more details.

But if I use

```
brew services start mongodb
```

then mongo server can start.

To fix the mongod error

I found the similar error thread

[Error while upgrading Mongodb from 3.2 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318487/error-while-upgrading-mongodb-from-3-2-to-3-6)

So I downgraded to mongodb 3.6, and run

```
db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

and then reinstall mongodb 4.0, I still have the same error when I run

```
mongodb
```

I still have to use

```
brew services start mongodb
```

to start mongodb

In command line, I run

```
> db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )
{ "featureCompatibilityVersion" : { "version" : "3.6" }, "ok" : 1 }
>
```

It says featureCompatibilityVersion is 3.6

What else I need to do to satisfy "The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.6 "?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to run purge command first to completely uninstall 3.6 and then start installing 4.0 from scratch...

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyWinzlet. I downgraded mongodb to 3.2. and clean up all the versions. step by step, upgrade to 3.4, 3.6 and 4.0. if the error show up, then based on the version I am upgrading to. run 

db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.x" } )

Now finally it is updated to 4.0.

Also in the previous upgrades, I lost a few databases. But now, after this step by step upgrades. I got these databases back too.

Comment: Please don't add your answer in the question. Post an answer instead.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I need to downgrade MongoDB to 3.4. Clean up all the versions. Then upgrade to 3.6 and 4.0 step by step.

**First of all, back up your /data/db, just in case.**

The following steps are from my experience, I used brew to install/uninstall mongodb.

I followed the instruction from this thread, but run the following steps on iMac.

[Error while upgrading Mongodb from 3.2 to 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318487/error-while-upgrading-mongodb-from-3-2-to-3-6)

**Uninstall your current mongodb**

```
brew uninstall mongodb
```

**Install mongodb 3.4 version**

```
brew install mongodb@3.4
```

**Start mongod 3.4 version** (when you install the old version like above, you need the full path to run it.)

```
/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.4/bin/mongod
```

**Start mongo 3.4 version**

```
/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.4/bin/mongo
```

**Run the important command**

```
> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )
```

**Quit**

```
>quit();
```

**Terminate the mongod**

```
Find PID of mongod process using $ top

Kill the process by $ kill <PID> (the Mongo docs have more info on this)
```

**Uninstall mongodb 3.4**

```
brew uninstall mongodb@3.4
```

Repeat the above steps for 3.6

**Install mongodb 3.6 version**

```
brew install mongodb@3.6
```

**Start mongod 3.6 version**

```
/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin/mongod
```

**Start mongo 3.6 version**

```
/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin/mongo
```

**Run the important command**

```
> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )
```

...

Last, after uninstall 3.6, then you can install the most current version, 4.x, you don't have to specify the @4.x etc., just

**Install the most current version**

```
brew install mongodb
```

Comment: Excuse me, may you post more detail steps?

Comment: Thanks for this! Just a heads up, you don't need to setFeatureCompatibilityVersion for 3.2 as it doesn't support that functionality.

Comment: Why do we have to do this? That's so many steps to just install

Comment: **Make sure to run `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` in correct database**

Somehow I have homebrew setup with a different database (i.e. not `/data/db`). After running through this process, the default database (`/data/db`) was up to date and working, but running `brew services start mongodb` would not work. To fix, instead of running `/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.4/bin/mongod`, I ran `brew services start mongodb@3.4`, and then `/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.4/bin/mongo` to connect and setFeatureCompatibilityVersion. This made homebrew use the db that is setup with homebrew (`/data/otherDb`)

Comment: A little addition, for everyone still stumbling over this issue.

Mongodb is installed from their own sources now, there is no "mongodb" directly in brew anymore:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodbs-official-brew-tap-now-open-and-flowing

And the paths are also different (`mongodb-community` instead of just `mongodb` for the executeable)

Comment: Same data files too old issue after I updated to mongodb-community@5.0. "mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf" just would not start. I checked the log. find this error:msg":"This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier.". I googled and found this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141258/this-version-of-mongodb-is-too-recent-to-start-up-on-the-existing-data-files-tr. The dbpath is "/usr/local/var/mongodb" now

Answer (score 1):

I would better just do it via mongodump/mongorestore procedures.

Comment: This one fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

thx @searain, this procedure worked also on Ubuntu, I just had to adapt the commands, for those who are interested:

Commands for Ubuntu 16.04

### Backup database and mongod.conf

`sudo cp -rp /var/lib/mongodb/ mongobackup/`

`sudo cp -p /etc/mongod.conf mongobackup/`

### Uninstall v4

`sudo service mongod stop`

`sudo apt purge mongodb-org*`

### Install v3.4

Copy installation commands from [docs@v3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

#### List available versions

`sudo apt list -a mongodb-org`

#### Install specific version

`sudo apt install -y mongodb-org=3.4.22 mongodb-org-server=3.4.22 mongodb-org-shell=3.4.22 mongodb-org-mongos=3.4.22 mongodb-org-tools=3.4.22 --allow-downgrades`

Start service

`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

`sudo service mongod start`

#### Login to mongo as admin

`mongo -u "dba" -p "..." --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

#### Issue command

Read more about `setFeatureCompatibilityVersion` in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/setFeatureCompatibilityVersion/index.html).

`db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )`

If status is not `ok` but `not authorized` try:

`db.grantRolesToUser('admin', [{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }])`

### Uninstall v3.4

`sudo service mongod stop`

`sudo apt purge mongodb-org*`

### Install v3.6

Copy installation commands from [docs@v3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

#### List available versions

`sudo apt list -a mongodb-org`

#### Install specific version

`sudo apt install -y mongodb-org=3.6.14 mongodb-org-server=3.6.14 mongodb-org-shell=3.6.14 mongodb-org-mongos=3.6.14 mongodb-org-tools=3.6.14`

#### Start service

`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

`sudo service mongod start`

#### Login to mongo as admin

`mongo -u "dba" -p "..." --authenticationDatabase "admin"`

#### Issue command

`db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6" } )`

### Uninstall v3.6

`sudo service mongod stop`

`sudo apt purge mongodb-org*`

### Install v4

`sudo apt install -y mongodb-org`

#### Check config

During this process, the mongod.conf might have been lost. Make sure authorization is enabled:

`sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf`

Needs:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

#### Start service

`sudo systemctl enable mongod`

`sudo service mongod start`