# Mongo suddenly stopped working with "too recent" error, but I didn't upgrade it

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting this error after removing the lock file and running `mongod.exe --repair` from the command line.

```
This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier
```

**I was literally just using the database** with an express app that I'm developing when the service crashed, and now it won't restart or repair. Since I'm not an expert on Mongo I need some help recovering from this.

I don't have any other versions of mongo installed, **nor have I done any upgrades**. I don't care so much about the data, other than trying to preserve my admin db where I've got all my authentication configured.

How do I get mongo running again?

**EDIT:** This question, which was suggested as an answer was the first thing I looked at.

[This version of MongoDB is too recent to start up on the existing data files. Try MongoDB 4.2 or earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141258/this-version-of-mongodb-is-too-recent-to-start-up-on-the-existing-data-files-tr)

It was unhelpful because, as I've mentioned already, I was already running mongo. The service crashed, and when I tried to restart the service, I'm getting the error. But I did not upgrade. The database files appear to be corrupted.