# Install mongod 4.03 but mongod still show db version v3.4.15

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I upgraded mongod to version 4.0.3, but when I run mongod --version, I still get.
MongoDB shell version v3.4.15

I stop the service before upgraded, I restarted the service, but I still getting the same version.

Comment: do you use windows?

Comment: Please look into `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999360/upgrading-mongodb-has-no-effect-and-still-shows-the-old-version`

Comment: I am using Linux.. I have tried this stackoverflow, but it did not work...

Comment: My mongod on /usr/bin/mongod still show date of May... it seems that the installation is not copying the bin to /usr/bin